# How can I the edit the config of a running smart-rollup-node?

Tags: smart-rollup

I would like to edit some of the configuration options for a rollup-node while it's running. Fore example I would like to add `"log-kernel-debug": true` to the config of a running rollup-node and start capturing the kernel.log.

I've tried the following command `octez-smart-rollup-node-PtMumbai config update --log-kernel-debug`. This produces an error "Unexpected command line option --log-kernel-debug."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not yet enabled. Follow
https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/issues/6086